# Writing a DSL method in ruby that will create a method with arguments

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, jruby, dsl

I'm attempting to write a DSL for a background worker class, and I'm a little stuck trying to accomplish something.

Ideally, I should be able to write a job worker like the following...

```
job :job_name do |param1, param2|
  puts param1
end
```

Now, in my worker superclass class, I'm doing something like this...

```
class Worker
  def self.job(job_name, &block)
    define_method job_name do
      # stuck
    end
    # do some additional stuff here
  end
end
```

What I **want** to do is define a method that has access to the block arguments that were used in the original job call, so I could fire this job off with:

```
Worker.new.job_name(param1, param2)
```

The method created should be functionally equivalent to:

```
def job_name(param1, param2)
  puts param1
end
```

Does that make any sense?  Hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you look for something like this:

```
class Worker
  def self.job(job_name, &block)
    define_method job_name, &block
    # do some additional stuff here
  end
end

Worker.job(:my_job) do |a,b| 
  puts "Called #{__method__} with param <#{a}> and <#{b}>"
end

#~ What I want to do is define a method that has access to the block arguments that were used in the original job call, so I could fire this job off with:
Worker.new.my_job(:param1,:param2) #-> Called my_job with param <param1> and <param2>
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Nice answer. +1

Comment: Works like a dream.  I was getting so close. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
class Worker
  def self.job(job_name, &block)
    define_method job_name, block
  end
end

Worker.job("foo"){ |x,y| puts "#{x} + #{y}" }
Worker.new.foo(1,2) # => 1 + 2
```